# RabbitMQ naming convention for queues and exchanges?

Tags: rabbitmq, naming-conventions

I came across a statement in a [tutorial](https://www.udemy.com/rabbitmq-java-spring-boot-for-system-integration/) on Udemy, that it is "good practice" to prefix queues with `q.` and exchanges with `x.`

Unfortunately, I could not really verify that anywhere... Is there any convention like this, or a resource that pointed this out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know about prefixing `queues` with `q.` and `exchanges` with `x.`. But, it is considered a good practice to prefixing or suffixing your mirrored queues or exchanges with the keyword `mirror`.

In a cluster system, you will be needing `policies` which will help you `mirror` your `queues` and `exchanges`. In order to identify which `queues` are to be `mirrored`, the keyword, `mirror` will help. And the queues which you don't want to mirror, you can add a keyword `no_mirror`. In case of exclusive queues, you can prefix or suffix with `ex`.

Also adding the word `q` or `queue` to the `queues` and `x` to `exchange` will enhance readability.

Comment: Why does that enhance readability? Won't it be clear which is which just based on where they are used?